# Необходимо выбрать только элемент .div, где написано yes

Tags: html, css

```
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ol>
            <li>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
            </li>
        </ol>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div>YES</div>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
                <div>NO</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Сделать это нужно с помощью псевдоклассов. Прописываю `ul li:nth-child(3)`, но оно выбирает yes вместе с другими div-ами. Подскажите, как обратиться **только** к yes?

Comment: У вас внутри `ul` несколько `li` и вы определили, как обратиться к нужному по счёту, но ведь и `ul` у вас несколько. Остаётся выбрать нужный: [:nth-of-type()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

Comment: Точно, и к первому `.div` потом обратиться с помощью `:first-child`. Спасибо огромное!